# Use pandas only to get all possible combination of 15 minute time blocks for a given start time, end time, and available time block?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, combinations

A machine with ID M1 has operation start time as `0 days 04:52:00` and end time as `0 days 08:54:00`. Essentially, the machine is only operating for 4 hr 2 minutes in an entire day with 1198 minutes available for maintenance (AT). The time required for maintenance is 65 minutes. I want a list of all combinations of 65 minutes from 1198 minutes available within the window `0 days 08:55:00` to `1 days 04:51:00` until it starts the service next day.

```
MID ST              ET              AT
M1  0 days 04:52:00 0 days 08:54:00 1198
```

What I have tried?

The code discussed in [Create five minute time blocks (Pandas/Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850658/create-five-minute-time-blocks-pandas-python) is only applicable for a given timestamp not newly generated timestamp.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not do your homework for you.  What have you tried writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass to that function **StartDate** and **EndDate** and **Interval**:
In your case:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def datetime_range(start, end, delta):
    current = start
    while current < end:
        yield current
        current += delta

start = datetime.now() + pd.Timedelta(days=1)
end = start + pd.Timedelta(minutes=1198)
interval = timedelta(minutes=65)

dts = [dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d T%H:%M Z') for dt in 
       datetime_range(start, end, interval)]

print(dts)
```

---

print block (scopes):

```
def splitIntoBlocks(dts):
    for i in range(len(dts)):
        print ('block ' + dts[i] + '-' + dts[i+1])

splitIntoBlocks(dts)
```

Comment: I am receiving this error "module 'pandas' has no attribute 'TimeDelta'"

Comment: typo - change TimeDelta into Timedelta

Comment: The code gives the start time only with 65 minutes interval ['2021-09-23 T15:04 Z', '2021-09-23 T16:09 Z', '2021-09-23 T17:14 Z'. How can I get both start and end time to represent it as a block. Also the gap between any two start time is 65 minutes. However, the difference can be as low as 1 minutes.

Comment: @vp_050 edited- instead print - there is option just to add new column to a dataframe

Comment: Thanks. How can we increase the start time by 1 minute for each block. Essentially, if block 1 is block 2021-09-23 T15:28 Z-2021-09-23 T16:33 Z. Then, block 2 is block 2021-09-23 T15:29 Z-2021-09-23 T16:34 Z.

Comment: Can we format as pandas timedelta not strftime (string object) for the above code?